# Should there be a common Q&A for how to take delayed screenshots?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Please look at these two questions:

- [Print Screen key doesn't work if a drop-down menu is active](https://askubuntu.com/q/72208/25656)
- [Taking screenshots in Lubuntu (11.10) [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/q/184618/25656)

Although the first question didn't specify a specific desktop environment, the answer there relates to Unity/GNOME. The second question, even though it specifically asks about Lubuntu, was marked as a duplicate of the first even though the first doesn't address taking delayed screenshots in Lubuntu.

Anyway, would it be worth having a broader question that covers how to take delayed screenshots using software that comes **as default** with each official Ubuntu derivative? So the answer would have  subsections for:

- GNOME/Unity (gnome-screenshot)
- Kubuntu (KSnapshot)
- Lubuntu (scrot)
- Xubuntu (xfce4-screenshooter)

My one concern is whether such a question will run foul of:

> This question is present as a matter of historical interest. While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and will be closed per the FAQ.

**Edit**: I've asked and answered the question here: [How do I take screenshots with a delay?](https://askubuntu.com/q/252281/25656).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, this seems like an excellent idea.

I recommend that this have **multiple answers, one per application**. Each answer can have the Ubuntu flavor and application at the top. For example:

> ### GNOME/Unity (regular Ubuntu) — gnome-screenshot
>
> Ordinarily, you would press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to take a screenshot.
>   This runs the `gnome-screenshot` utility. However, you can launch it
>   manually with command-line arguments specifying how long you want it
>   to wait before it takes the screenshot.
>
> In either the *Run command* textbox (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) or
>   a Terminal ***...***

<sup>*This is just an example. I don't actually know if `gnome-screenshot -d` is the best/easiest way.*</sup>

There should certainly be answers for all the official Ubuntu flavors' default screenshot utilities. But I don't think it needs to be limited to that. Some other applications--or at least one--may be covered.

In particular, in addition to answers for gnome-screenshot, KSnapshot, scrot, and xfce4-screenshooter, I think we should have one for GIMP. This popular program is very good for taking screenshots because it is versatile and powerful (though *not* lightweight, compared to pure screenshot utilities), and often one wishes to edit a screenshot immediately after taking it.

(If you post this question, I'd be pleased to write the GIMP answer.)

#### Why This Question Would Be Constructive

In response to concern that this would be considered a list question and closed:

"How to do X?" questions are not list questions. We have *many* good questions with multiple answers, where different answers apply to (and are marked as relating to) different Ubuntu releases or flavors, or different general *kinds* of technique (e.g., GUI vs. command-line).

- [What's the right terminology for Unity's UI elements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10228/whats-the-right-terminology-for-unitys-ui-elements)
- [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)
- [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)
- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)
- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)
- [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)
- [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)
- [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)
- [How do I configure Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32667/how-do-i-configure-unity-2d)
- [How do I get the latest GIMP version available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)
- [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)
- [Ubuntu One on Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36117/ubuntu-one-on-lubuntu)
- [How to burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)

Several of those even have indexes of answers by version *in the question*, and are considered perfectly good!

Furthermore--while "How to take a delayed screenshot?" would *not* be a list question--list questions are not actually considered bad. *Big list* questions, where there could be an unlimited number of answers that cannot be maintained or meaningfully compared to one another, are bad. Here are some open "small" list questions that are perfectly good--or at least highly tolerated:

- [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available)
- [How to record my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast)
- [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)
- [What virtualization software can I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41407/what-virtualization-software-can-i-use)

And there are even some questions with a potentially unlimited number of answers, that are considered good, because they are not lists of software, but rather of methods and techniques (and so are similar to a question that just happens to have a lot of answers):

- [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)
- [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

At exactly what point a list question becomes a big list question and is subject to closure is a little fuzzy, and I'm sure there's disagreement over where the threshold should be set for that. But **asking for methods to take a delayed screenshot** is quite specific; **that is not a big list question**.

Furthermore, *even* if you plan to add an answer index to the question, you don't have to actually say, "one program/technique per answer please." Instead, ask the question and post whatever answers you want.

- If you've already posted an answer and want to split it into multiple answers, that's fast. (All, or all but one, should probably be community wiki. Please note that you don't need the assistance of a moderator to make an *answer* CW.)
- If you're first writing the question, click the checkbox for answering your own question, and compose at least one of the answers. You can actually compose them together (benefiting from the formatted preview), then separate each section into a separate plaintext document on your computer (make sure to convey any corresponding link/image URLs from the bottom of the answer, to whichever document they correspond to). Then you can have one answer posted immediately, and the others posted in well under a minute.

  This has the advantage of *showing* people the benefit of having one flavor/application per answer. If they want to break with that format, *that's fine*! This fineness is an important indicator that your question is appropriate, and not a "big list" question.

By the same token, if you've posted your question and posted an answer covering multiple applications, and you don't want to split it, **that really is fine too.**

Comment: @vasa1 I don't think "How to take a delayed screenshot?" would be categorized as a big list question either. Furthermore, unless you can actually make the default screenshot tool delay when you press Print Screen--and even then, perhaps--the restriction you propose seems artificial. I'll edit to explain in greater detail.

Comment: @vasa1 I don't think it's necessary for the *question* to be CW. This may even make it less constructive, by discouraging others from contributing answers. (I will still contribute my GIMP answer, if it's on-topic. But I suspect it will not be, given the way you've characterized the question.) If you post more than one answer yourself, I recommend making the *answers* CW (or perhaps all but one of them). I see no reason for the *question* to be CW. One way this isn't (or shouldn't be) a list question is that *other people should be free to contribute answers that break with the format*.

Comment: @vasa1 Also, considering the form of your answer, this is no different from any other non-list question. You can of course ask for it to be CW'd, but I recommend against it. (Still working on the edit to this answer.)

Comment: @vasa1 I've found your question ...but if you want people reading this meta question to know about the question you've created, you might want to put a link to it somewhere here. (Maybe in an edit at the bottom of the meta question? I recommend against *replacing* anything in your meta question with it, you can just add it to the bottom with a short explanation of what it is.)

Comment: @EliahKagan, will add the link at the end of the question.