# Can someone make clear rules about the "software-recommendation" tag?

Tags: discussion, scope

Ok, apparently we don't have a clear set of rules about the [software-recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation):

> As long as any answer is *correct*, the question is not a place for Ask Ubuntu. – Braiam 4 hours ago
>
> @braiam any question with the tag software-recommendation would go like that. How can you have a wrong "recommendation"?! @hash thanks!! – Mina Michael 7 mins ago

So, can we establish a **very clear** set of rules about this "software recommendation" questions? I've read the tag wiki, but in some points I feel that it goes against the FAQ:

> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

So, we need to close them and done? We need a better guide? Remember that none of the SE sites allows *-recommendation stuff, then should we?

Comment: I did have a go not so long ago... On my phone at the moment but it's out there somewhere.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6264/169736 ? or http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6184/on-topic-what-games-can-be-played-by-two-people-on-the-same-computer/6186#6186?

Comment: On my phone as well or I would write something.

Comment: This has been addressed a number of times. Ask Ubuntu has been around for over three years now, we don't come across a lot of new issues to be addressed ;)